# How to link delegate and datasource to multiple tableviews in one ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I created two `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`. To link to the `delegate` and `datasource` I used the basic method, holding Ctrl and dragging to the "yellow ball" above. However, I can only do this with one, when each `UITableView` should separately have its own database in the class. When I do the same with the second `UITableView`, it apparently links the same `datasource` and `delegate` to both, without extracting the data from the class to the second and displaying them on the screen.

How can I fix that?

```
//I declared four buttons, two in each table view.    

    @IBOutlet weak var btnDrop: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!


    @IBOutlet weak var btnDropProj: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tblViewProj: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tblView.isHidden = true
        tblViewProj.isHidden = true


    }

var selectClient = ["Cliente 1", "Cliente 2", "Cliente 3", "Cliente 4", "Cliente 5", "Cliente 6", "Cliente 7", "Cliente 8"]

var selectProject = ["Projeto 1", "Projeto 2", "Projeto 3", "Projeto 4", "Projeto 5", "Projeto 6", "Projeto 7", "Projeto 8"]
```

Comment: (I'm not sure what you're asking but I'll give one possible answer.)  Your datasource and delegate methods are called with a table view as a parameter.  You can test which one it is before returning data.

Comment: In every delegate and dataSource method you can check is `if tableView == table1 else if tableView == table2` etc. Or create separate classes for delegate and data sources and add them programmatically to each tableView

Comment: Please post your delegate and datasource method here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are trying to link your table views to 2 different data sources.

You can do that by first creating 2 separate data sources like below.

```swift
class Table1DataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    // Properties
    private var table1Data: [String]

    init(table1Data: [String]) {
        self.table1Data = table1Data

        super.init()
    }

    // MARK: - Data Source

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.table1Data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var profileCell: ProfileCell

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Table1Cell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! Table1Cell

        // Initialize the cell here

        return cell

    }

}
```

After that you can link the data source to your table view in your controller.

```swift
class MainController: UIViewController {

    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tblViewProj: UITableView!

    // Properties
    var selectClient = ["Cliente 1", "Cliente 2", "Cliente 3", "Cliente 4", "Cliente 5", "Cliente 6", "Cliente 7", "Cliente 8"]
    var selectProject = ["Projeto 1", "Projeto 2", "Projeto 3", "Projeto 4", "Projeto 5", "Projeto 6", "Projeto 7", "Projeto 8"]

    // DataSource
    lazy var tblViewDataSource: Table1DataSource = {
        return Table1DataSource(table1Data: self.selectClient)
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tblView.dataSource = self.tblViewDataSource
    }

}
```

All that's left to do is to repeat the steps to link your second table.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
// MARK: - UITableView datasource
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.tblView {
        return selectClient.count
    }
    else {
        return selectProject.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if tableView == self.tblView {
        let CellIdentifier: String = "YOURCUSTOMCELL"
        var cell: YOURCUSTOMCELL? = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier) as? YOURCUSTOMCELL)

        if cell == nil {
            let topLevelObjects: [Any] = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("YOURCUSTOMCELL", owner: nil, options: nil)!
            cell = (topLevelObjects[0] as? YOURCUSTOMCELL)
            cell?.selectionStyle = .none
        }
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return cell!
    }
    else {
        let CellIdentifier: String = "YOURCUSTOMCELL"
        var cell: YOURCUSTOMCELL? = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier) as? YOURCUSTOMCELL)

        if cell == nil {
            let topLevelObjects: [Any] = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("YOURCUSTOMCELL", owner: nil, options: nil)!
            cell = (topLevelObjects[0] as? YOURCUSTOMCELL)
            cell?.selectionStyle = .none
        }
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return cell!
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if tableView == self.tblView {
        return 50.0
    }
    else {
        return 50.0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)   {
    if tableView == self.tblView {

    }
    else {
    }
}
```